# Encapsulation and auxiliary functions for using UDP sockets on a client and server

Tags: c, function, network-programming, udp, client-server

I am using the UDP auxiliary functions encapsulated below replacing the calls the functions of the sockets libraries to simulate and allow some testing on the UDP client and server. But I am not able to make the connection between them and pass the arguments correctly.

```
/********auxiliary functions for using UDP sockets*********/
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netdb.h>
    #include <strings.h>

    #include "tp_socket.h"

    #define MTU 1024 

    int tp_mtu(void)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"tp_mtu called\n");

        return MTU;
    }

    int tp_sendto(int so, char* buff, int buff_len, so_addr* to_addr)
    {
        int count;
        fprintf(stderr,"tp_sendto called (%d bytes)\n", buff_len);

        count = sendto(so, (void*)buff, buff_len, 0,
                (struct sockaddr*) to_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
        fprintf(stderr,"tp_sendto returning (sent %d bytes)\n", count);
        return count;

    }

    int tp_recvfrom(int so, char* buff, int buff_len, so_addr* from_addr)
    {
        int count;
        unsigned int sockaddr_len = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);
        fprintf(stderr,"tp_recvfrom called (%d bytes)\n",buff_len);

        count = recvfrom(so,(void*)buff,(size_t)buff_len,0,
                (struct sockaddr*) from_addr, &sockaddr_len);
        fprintf(stderr,"tp_recvfrom returning (received %d bytes)\n",count);
        return count;
    }

    int tp_init(void)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"tp_init called\n");

        return 0;
    }


    int tp_socket(unsigned short port)
    {
        int    so;
        struct sockaddr_in local_addr;
        int    addr_len =sizeof(local_addr);

        fprintf(stderr,"tp_socket called\n");
        if ((so=socket(PF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,0))<0) {
            return -1;
        }
        if (tp_build_addr(&local_addr,INADDR_ANY,port)<0) {
            return -2;
        }
        if (bind(so, (struct sockaddr*)&local_addr, sizeof(local_addr))<0) {
            return -3;
        }
        return so;
    }

    int tp_build_addr(so_addr* addr, char* hostname, int port)
    {
        struct hostent* he;

        fprintf(stderr,"tp_build_addr called\n");
        addr->sin_family = PF_INET;
        addr->sin_port   = htons(port);
        if (hostname==NULL) {
            addr->sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        } else {
            if ((he=gethostbyname(hostname))==NULL) {
                return -1;
            }
            bcopy(he->h_addr,&(addr->sin_addr.s_addr),sizeof(in_addr_t));
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

My code at the moment of the UDP client:

```
/********clientUDP*********/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include "tp_socket.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    so_addr to_addr;
    char *ip_server;
    char my_buffer[10];
    int port_servidor, tam_buffer;

    if (argc != 5)
    {
        perror("Error");
        exit(-1);
    }
    *ip_server = argv[1];
    port_server = atoi(argv[2]);
    char arquivo = argv[3];
    tam_buffer = atoi(argv[4]);


    tp_init();
    tp_socket(port);
    tp_build_addr(&to_addr, ip_server, port_server);


    exit(0);

}
```

My code at the moment of the UDP server:

```
/********serverUDP*********/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include "tp_socket.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    so_addr my_addr;

    int aux, so, mtu, port_server,tam_buffer,n;
    char *archive;
    char buffer[10];
    FILE *file;

    if (argc != 3)
    {
        perror("Error");
        exit(-1);
    }
    port_server = atoi(argv[1]);
    tam_buffer = atoi(argv[2]);

    aux = tp_init();
    if (aux < 0)
    {
        perror("error");
        exit(aux);
    }

    mtu = tp_mtu();

    so = tp_socket(port_server);

    tp_recvfrom(so, buffer, 10 , &my_addr);

    n = read( so,tam_buffer,1);


     file = fopen(archive,"r");
     if ( file != NULL )
     {
        n=fread(buffer,1,atoi(argv[2]),file);

        while ( n > 0)
        {
            write(so,buffer,n);
            n=fread(buffer,1, atoi(argv[2]),file);
        }
     } else
        {
        printf("error\n");
        exit(0);
        }


    fclose(file);
    shutdown(so,2);

    close();



    return 0;
}
```

Could someone please explain how I use the auxiliary functions to connect the client to the server and transfer files?  I've be I've been locked up a long time at this stage.

Comment: Who wrote the 'auxilliary UDP functions'?  What documentation did they provide?  They're not standard functions.  What makes you think they're useful to you given that you don't know what they're for or how to use them?

Comment: Note that UDP doesn't make connections.  Messages are sent.  Sometimes they arrive where they are sent.  Messages are sent back.  Sometimes they arrive.  In fact, usually 'sometimes' means 'almost all the time', but that isn't guaranteed by UDP.  And there's no guarantee that the messages are received in the order sent, in either direction.  If you want reliable connections, use TCP, not UDP.

Comment: Google doesn't seem to recognize `tp_socket.h` or `tp_sendto()` except as referenced in this question.  That suggests you need to contact the author of the code to find out more about how to use the functions.